# Retrieve drawable resource from Uri

Tags: android, uri, android-drawable

I'm storing the drawable resource path in an Uri in this way:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://my_app_package/drawable/drawable_name");
```

How do I get the Drawable that the uri is referencing?

I don't want to put it in an ImageView, just retrieve the Drawable (or Bitmap) object.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`getContentResolver cr object` then call:

```
is = cr.openInputStream(uri)
```

and finally call:

```
Drawable.createFromStream(InputStream is, String srcName)
```

...Here's an actual working code example so you can see for yourself:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(yourUri);
    yourDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, yourUri.toString() );
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    yourDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_image);
}
```

Comment: thanks! I chose to edit @pskink's answer (vs. providing a new answer) since I could only take partial credit.

Comment: Note: you may have to also call `yourDrawable.setBounds(...)`, in some cases like setting it as a compound drawable of a `TextView`

Comment: What @AvinashR mentions is correct, if not the drawable won't be draw on screen.