# Change image on activityresult

Tags: android

I start the chooser activity

```
selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open from"), PICK_IMAGE);
    }
});
```

and I have to change an `imageview` picture with the result, I'm not sure but the resultCode variable from `onActivityResult` has -1 value

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        //get data and change imageView
    }
}
```

But I don't know get the data from the Intent data to set the picture of the `imageView`

Comment: Use an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso.

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: Sure it is. Lots of developers use them.

Comment: It's a student exercise ,has some rules

Comment: The rules should say "use what professionals use". Professionals use image-loading libraries, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the -1 in the resultCode means that the action was successful. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK)

The path to the File you find in the Intent data. You can access it like this:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Then you can set the ImageView to this URI:

```
ImageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

But thanks to the comment and according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) this is not recommended. As alternative use `ImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable)` or `ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)` as stated in the docs.

So here they explain how to use setImageBitmap:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717740/6845698

And here how to get a drawable from an Uri, which you can set then with setImageDrawable:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718935/6845698

Which to use depends on your needs like file type.

Comment: `setImageURI()` blocks the main application thread for loading and decoding the image. This approach is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

-1 is the constant value for [RESULT_OK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) which means your activity that was started for a result completed successfully.

Use your debugger to break on `onActivityResult` method. Inspect the `data` Intent you get back. It should have either:

1: a Bitmap object that is the image that was obtained or

2: a URI that is the path to the image you can then load using something like Glide or Picasso.

See [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskCaptureIntent) in the docs for more.

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will return a `Uri`.