# How to add URI of multiple Images to StickerView?

Tags: android, image, uri

I'm trying to add multiple images in StickerView using URI but StickerView does not accept URI. How can we pass URI to stickerview in order to add multiple images to a single screen with stickerview functionality

Comment: if `StickerView` accept `drawable` then convert URI to drawable and set in stickerview. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718935/6847390) for convert URI to drawable

Comment: Thanks @JatinK. this resolved my issue.